# How to handle more keys at the same time?

Tags: javascript, jquery, keydown, easeljs

I am making a game with easel js and jQuery.
I woud like to handle multiple pressed keys at the same time.
I have this bit of code for one key:

```
$(document).keydown(function(e){
if (e.keyCode == 37) { 
   angle=angle+1;

}
if (e.keyCode == 40) { 
   rad=angle*Math.PI/180;
   charachter.x=charachter.x-speed*Math.cos(rad);
   charachter.y=charachter.y-speed*Math.sin(rad);

   stage.update();
}
if (e.keyCode == 39) { 
   angle=angle-1;


}
if (e.keyCode == 38) { 
   rad=angle*Math.PI/180;
   charachter.x=charachter.x+speed*Math.cos(rad);
   charachter.y=charachter.y+speed*Math.sin(rad);

   stage.update();
}

});
```

But how do I make it so it is rotating and moving foward at the same time?

Comment: You might need to save which keys are pressed on key down and continue their action on a timer until key up.

Comment: take a look here: https://github.com/ccampbell/mousetrap

Comment: You'll also need to stop *all* keys when the right mouse button is used, or when the window loses focus.

Comment: Because I'm feeling generous (and largely because I haven't written any fun code in a while) [here's a quick example of how to listen to multiple keys being pressed](http://codepen.io/zzzzBov/pen/mugKt).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both of the events you are looking for will happen inside that listener. If you want to create an action that continues to run after the key has been pressed you need to perform that action inside a loop and activate it with your event listener. so for example ....

```
$(document).keydown(function(e){
    if (e.keyCode == 40) { 
       turn = true;
    }
    if (e.keyCode == 38) { 
       move = true;
    }
});

setTimeout(function() {
    if(turn) {
       // turn
    }
    if(move) {
      // move
    }
}, 1000 / 24);
```

then just listen for those keys to go up in a keyup listener and set turn/move to false.

Comment: suddenly your character is turning and moving forever. You might want to add a `keyup` listener...

Comment: ty but keys 39 and 37 are turn not 40 but ty anyway

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you are not able to do what you want. The only keys that can be pressed simultaneously are **ctrl**, **shift** and **alt**:

```
$(document).keydown(function(e){
    var ctrl = e.ctrlKey,
    shift = e.shiftKey,
    alt = e.altKey,
    altGr = e.altGraphKey,
    code = e.keycode || e.which;    
    if(code==='65' && ctrl){
        //Ctrl+A
    }
    if(code==='65' && shift){
        //Shift+A
    }
    if(code==='65' && alt){
        //Alt+A
    }
    if(code==='65' && altGr){
        //AltGr+A
    }
});
```

However, I don't know if this example works in all major browsers (will work on Chrome, Firefox, Safari and maybe Opera and IE).

Another way is to do what @MrOBrian said, saving the pressed keys in an array:

```
var keys = [];
$(document).keydown(function(e){
    var key = e.keyCode || e.which;
    if(keys.indexOf(key)===-1)
        keys.push(key);
    if(keys[0]===65 && keys[0]===66){
        //A and B pressed, respectively
    }
    if(keys.indexOf(67)!==-1 && keys.indexOf(68)!==-1){
        //C and D pressed, the order doesn't matter
    }
});
$(document).keyup(function(){
    keys = [];
});
```

This way, whenever you press a key, it will be stored in the `keys` array (unless it has already been stored) and then the program will check the keys that were pressed and, finally, when the user "mouses up", the array will be reset.

**NOTE**:
Let's suppose the keys pressed were **A** and **B**, respectively. If you want to check if they were pressed in this order, you have to use this condition:

```
if(keys[0]===65 && keys[0]===66){
    //A and B pressed, respectively
}
```

But, if you just want to check if they were pressed and the order doesn't matter, you just have to check if they are in the `keys` array, with this condition:

```
if(keys.indexOf(65)!==-1 && keys.indexOf(66)!==-1){
    //A and B pressed, the order doesn't matter
}
```

Comment: Just because a key has stopped triggering its `keydown` event doesn't mean that it's no longer being pressed. You simply need to store a reference to which keys are actively being pressed, and remove them from the reference when you receive a `keyup` event for that key.

Comment: Much better. I prefer to use an object as a hashtable instead of an array. Just remember to clear the entire set of keys whenever the page loses focus or the user right-clicks. After those events, it's possible that the user could change key states without the key handlers being notified. There might be additional events (contextmenu?) where key events can be hidden.